# Implement Socket Mobile QR Scanner with web application

Tags: angularjs, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am new to this kind of developing with device and web application. What I doubt about is, can I implement **Socket Mobile QR Scanner or any QR Scanner** mobile with web application? If can, can you guide me with a few step, so I can get confidence and start implementing and testing with real device!

I will create an web application in Laravel and Angular Js handling some purchase transaction. What I want is, there will be a product generated QR code on the parcel, whenever I scan that with QR Scanner, the application should get the code and push it to server to process with the transaction!

Thanks you a lot for helping me out! I hope I could get any clues soon!